# Appending Get-Content of two files to new file in Powershell inserts spaces between characters

Tags: python, powershell

I'm writing the following in Powershell:

```
Get-Content "Path/to/InputFile1/InputFile1.txt" -totalcount 250| Out-File -FilePath "Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt" -Append

Get-Content "Path/to/InputFile2/InputFile2.txt" -totalcount 250| Out-File -FilePath "Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt" -Append
```

I checked the size of `OutputFile.txt` and noticed it was exactly double the size I had expected. I checked to make sure everything looked ok in Powershell using the following:

```
Get-Content "Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt" -totalcount 1
```

Nothing looked out of the ordinary. I then went into Python, and checked a snippet using the following:

```
f = open("Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt","rb")
f = f.read()
print f[0:20]
```

and noticed an unusual output. Whereas the initial file's snippet looked like `00102xxxx,5197609,Je`, the output file's snippet looked like the following:  `■0 0 1 0 2 x x x x`. Is there an explanation behind this odd behavior? It would appear specific to Python if it wasn't for the fact that the output file is exactly double what I would expect it to be. I'm not sure how the alternating spaces are occurring. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the input text is encoded as ASCII (8 bits per character), and the Out-File cmdlet outputs the file as Unicode (16 bits per character... i.e. double the size). The same number of characters are outputted, just the encoding is different.

If you want to change it back to ASCII (as you probably expect), set the `-Encoding "ASCII"` parameter, so your text looks like this:

```
Get-Content "Path/to/InputFile1/InputFile1.txt" -totalcount 250| Out-File -Encoding "ASCII" -FilePath "Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt" -Append

Get-Content "Path/to/InputFile2/InputFile2.txt" -totalcount 250| Out-File -Encoding "ASCII" -FilePath "Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt" -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed an explanation. You have an *Encoding problem*. Figure out the encoding `Powershell` is using, since is Windows, I assume `UCS-2` and in python do:

```
f = open("Path/to/OutputFile/OutputFile.txt","rb")
f = f.read().decode('utf16')
print f[0:20].encode('utf-8')
```

Hope this helps!